# Sencha Touch 2: Set a store from an array

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to create a store, which I can then create a list from.  The problem is when I create the store, it is empty.

This is my model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.TrackingCode', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            'id',
            'code',
            'count'
        ]
    }
});
```

And here's the code where I am trying to populate the store:

```
var tc = [{id: 1, code: 'abc', count: 5}];
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'MyApp.model.TrackingCode',
  data: tc
});
```

The summary for console.log(store); shows this:

Class {_proxy: Class, data: Class, _totalCount: null, eventDispatcher: Class, initialConfig: Object…}

Which shows the total count value as null, so I don't think my store is getting populated.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you create the store on the fly ? Why don't you create it before and set its data afterwards ? Also just a quick thought, try to set the model to 'TrackingCode' and not actually 'MyApp.model.TrackingCode'

Comment: It could not find the model when I did not use the full reference to TrackingCode.  The tracking code array actually comes from a field in another store, let's say "books".  I have a carousel where I display the book title and image, then I need to make a list under that HTML on the same carousel slide of the tracking codes array. I am new to ST, maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_totalCount will be null when you load data by inline. _totalCount will have some value when you load data from server. In short _totalCount refers to the total set of data in server. So dont worry about it.

Try this

```
console.log(store.getCount());
```

This will return the exact count of data loaded in the store. If it returns some value, then your code is good.

Comment: Thanks, the store was actually being populated which helped me figure out the data it was being populated with needed to be formatted differently.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the "data" property inside Store's **config** object like this:

```
var tc = [{id: 1, code: 'abc', count: 5}];
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'MyApp.model.TrackingCode',
  config : {
    data: tc
  }
});
```

Comment: My list that I am attaching this store to will not populate if I define the data inside config.  It works fine outside of config now though.